# Экземпляры класса при создании в цикле дублируются

Tags: python, ооп, list, объекты, дублирование

Пишу бота для телеграмма. У меня есть суперкласс для работы с базой данных:

```
# в db настройки для подключения к базе данных 
import db
class MyClass:
    prop = {}
    id = 0
    table = ""
    isnew = False

    def __init__(self, id, table) -> None:
        self.id=id
        self.table=table

        if id==0:
            db.cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO {db.db_base}.{table} values ()")
            self.id= db.cursor.lastrowid
            db.conn.commit()
            id = self.id
        db.cursor.execute(f"SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name='{table}'")
        fields = db.cursor.fetchall()
        columns = []
        for field in fields:
            columns.append('`'+field[0]+'`')
        column_query = ", ".join(columns)
        db.cursor.execute(f"SELECT {column_query} FROM {db.db_base}.{table} WHERE ID = {id}")
        data = db.cursor.fetchone()

        i = -1
        for field in fields:
            i += 1
            self.prop.update({field[0]:data[i]})

    def update_data(self):
                
        query = ','.join([f'`{key}`="{value}"' for key, value in self.prop.items()]) 
        query = f"UPDATE `{db.db_base}`.`{self.table}` SET {query} WHERE `id` = {self.id}"
        db.cursor.execute(query)
        db.conn.commit()
```

У меня есть класс на основе этого суперкласса:

```
class StorageUser(MyClass):
    description = ''
    def __init__(self, tgid, name):
        id = is_user_exist(tgid)
        super().__init__(id, 'storages')
        if id==0:
            self.prop.update({"tgid":tgid})
        self.prop.update({"name":name})
        self.update_data()
```

И я пытаюсь сгенерировать список объектов класса `StorageUser` в цикле

```
from model import storage
i=0
x = []
while i<3:
    i += 1
    # get_tgid() и get_tgname() - функции, возвращающие данные для 
    # корректной генерации экземпляров класса. Они отдают на каждой
    # итерации соответствующие данные
    a = storage.StorageUser(storage.get_tgid(i),storage.get_tgname(i))
    x.append(a)
```

далее пытаюсь понять что у меня в списке и печатаю свойство класса

```
for a in x:
    print(a.prop.get('id'))

>> 3
>> 3
>> 3
```

То есть в результате я получаю список, состоящий из дублей экземпляров класса. Аналогичное поведение наблюдается и с циклом FOR и с генератором списков:

```
x = [storage.StorageUser(
        storage.get_tgid(i),
        storage.get_tgname(i))
        for i in [1,2,3]]
```

В дебаг-режиме посмотрел и это происходит следующим образом:

1. Первая итерация

   - Создаётся первый объект
   - Добавляется к списку
2. Вторая и последующая итерации

   - Создаётся новый объект, при этом старые объекты в списке становятся эквивалентны новому
   - Добавляется к списку: имеем n+1 экземпляров эквивалентных объектов в списке

Comment: А что у вас выдают функции `storage.get_tgid(i)` и `storage.get_tgname(i)` на каждой итерации - проверяли? Может они одно и то же выдают.

Comment: Ну и в целом у вас логика очень запутанная. Надо как-то упрощать.

Comment: @CrazyElf Эти функции возвращают данные из бд:
`storage.get_tgid(i)` - `id` пользователя Telegram;
`storage.get_tgname(i)` - `username` пользователя Telegram.
на каждой итерации они возвращают корректное значение (то есть разное)

Буду благодарен за рекомендации по упрощению, но главное чтобы я мог делать наборы объектов в циклах :)

Comment: @CrazyElf Загрузил видео процесса отладки https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VyqM4Ogq1F4 , честно говоря не знаю как подробнее объяснить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем, проблема чинится очень просто. Проблема тут:

```py
class MyClass:
    prop = {} # <-- общее поле для всех экземпляров класса!
    ...

    def __init__(self, id, table) -> None:
        ...
        self.prop.update({field[0]:data[i]})
```

У вас в экземплярах класса нет своего `self.prop`, у вас есть только `prop` как свойство класса. Питон в этом плане слишком свободный язык и когда вы начинаете использовать *свойство (переменную) экземпляра класса*, никак его не инициализировав, он говорит: ок, наверное вы хотите использовать *свойство класса*. Таким образом `self.prop` **в каждом экземпляре класса** ссылается на **один и тот же словарь**.

Чинится это очень просто: нужно инициализировать `self.prop` в экземпляре класса:

```py
class MyClass:
    # prop = {} <-- тут убираем
    ...

    def __init__(self, id, table) -> None:
        self.prop = {} # <-- сюда добавляем
        ...
        self.prop.update({field[0]:data[i]})
```

Собственно, проблема возникла только из-за того, что `prop` - это коллекция. Когда вы используете переменные класса типа "значение" в экземпляре класса, то они как бы "перетираются" новыми значениями и вы ничего не замечаете. А вот когда вы изменяете **содержимое коллекции**, то коллекция остаётся там же, где и была - в классе, хотя вы пользуетесь ей как полем экземпляра класса, и думаете, что это новая коллекция в экземпляре класса. А это совсем не так. В общем, нужно понимать, где класс, а где экземпляр, чем они отличаются и как себя ведут.

Comment: Всё получилось, спасибо! Пожалуйста, дополните ответ (в части кода), чтобы было понятно что нужно инициализировать свойство в дочернем классе до инициализации суперкласса (у меня так заработало), а не в суперклассе

Comment: Хм, а если в суперклассе, то не так как нужно работает? Мне кажется разницы нет, главное чтобы в экземпляре оно инициализировалось сразу в `__init__`, а в родителе это делать или в дочернем классе вроде бы без разницы, у них один и тот же `self` и `self.prop`, я даже на всякий случай это проверил встроенной функцией `id` (кстати, вы её зря перекрываете своей переменной).